# How to disallow different automake versions from overwriting each other's binary files

Tags: software-installation, automake

I was using `automake` **1.11** without trouble, until some package required `automake` **1.10**. When installing it, I found that it actually wants to overwrite `/usr/bin/{aclocal,automake}` (which were installed by **1.11**).

Here's my `./configure` command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

I would prefer the solution to involve the build files, as opposed to modifying the filesystem directly.

Answer (score 3):

You could install the old automake version into a different folder, such as:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/automake-1.10
```

Then when you want to use that version, make sure it gets picked up before the real/latest version:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/automake-1.10/bin:$PATH
automake --version
```

It doesn't have to go into /usr/local/automake-1.10 either, you can put it in your home directory so you don't need root access to install it, and it can be easily removed when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do anything.  Automake by default installs everything with a version suffix.  Whatever you installed last would be `automake`, but you can call `automake-1.10` and `automake-1.11` directly.